# Probleme with LoadRawTextureData and get white texture with random dot color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i got a probleme i try to load a texture with LoadRawTextureData, ingame i see white texture with random color dot

[image: Screenshot of the buggy texture]

```
byte[] temp = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\ds\Export\Texture2D\Deck_noLabel 2.png");
            int headerSize = 8;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[temp.Length - headerSize];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(temp, headerSize, buffer, 0, temp.Length - headerSize);
            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2048, 2048, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
            tex.LoadRawTextureData(buffer);
            tex.Apply();
            GameObject.Find("GripTape").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetTexture("Texture2D_4128E5C7", tex);
```

Comment: Hi, please have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Comment: You could try [UnityWebResquest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTexture.html) or [UnityWebRequestTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html)